# how to change the Excel Icon in Taskbar while loading

Tags: excel, icons

Is there any option to change the excel icon in taskbar for Excel?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I usually do not answer questions where the OP has shown no efforts but this was way too interesting to pass on. But do not be surprised if this question gets closed :)

> Is there any option to change the excel icon in taskbar for Excel

Yes there is. You have to use 3 APIs for this

`ExtractIcon32`, `GetActiveWindow32` and `SendMessage32`

To read about them see [THIS LINK](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php). This is my favorite one stop for APIs :)

```
Declare Function ExtractIcon32 Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
"ExtractIconA" (ByVal hInst As Long, _
ByVal lpszExeFileName As String, ByVal nIconIndex As Long) As Long

Declare Function GetActiveWindow32 Lib "user32" _
Alias "GetActiveWindow" () As Integer

Declare Function SendMessage32 Lib "user32" Alias _
"SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim myIcoFile As String
    Dim NewIco

    '~~> Change this to the relevant icon file
    myIcoFile = "D:\Temp\icons\CHARACT\$SIGN1.ico"

    NewIco = ExtractIcon32(0, myIcoFile, 0)

    SendMessage32 GetActiveWindow32(), &H80, 1, NewIco
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using Office 365 32 Bit on Windows 10 64 Bit and this doesn't work for me. Is there any change I can do for that?

Comment: It works for me in Office 2016 (32 bit) Win 10 (64 bit)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no idea why didn't work for Office 365 but if I reached a solution, I will post it for others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for 64 bit Excel

```
    #If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function ExtractIcon32 Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ExtractIconA" (ByVal hInst As LongPtr, ByVal lpszExeFileName As String, ByVal nIconIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow32 Lib "user32" Alias "GetActiveWindow" () As LongPtr 'Integer
    Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage32 Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function ExtractIcon32 Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ExtractIconA" (ByVal hInst As Long, ByVal lpszExeFileName As String, ByVal nIconIndex As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetActiveWindow32 Lib "user32" Alias "GetActiveWindow" () As Integer
    Declare Function SendMessage32 Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub auto_open()
    Dim myIcoFile As String
    Dim NewIco

    myIcoFile = Application.Path + "\POWERPNT.EXE"
    NewIco = ExtractIcon32(0, myIcoFile, 0)

    SendMessage32 GetActiveWindow32(), &H80, 1, NewIco
End Sub
```